# best way to reindex sphinx in ubuntu hardy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, debian, sphinx

I'm running a slice of ubuntu hardy.
I've installed sphinx, and I would like to run the sphinx indexer every `x` minutes.
What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 5):

The standard Unix approach is `cron`, so you could for example edit `/etc/crontab` and add a line like

```
*/5 * * * *     root    sphynx [whatever other options you need]
```

which means

- 'every five minutes' (for the */5 part)
- of every hour (the * in position 2)
- of every day of the month (the *  in position 3)
- of every month (the * in position 4)
- of every day of the week (the final * in position 5)

Another example: '4 5 * * 6' amounts to 'at 5:04am (four minutes after five) on every Saturday (day of the week is 6).

You may need to or want to switch the user from root to, say, www-data is sphynx runs as that, and you obviously need to adjust the arguments.

Lastly, look into the directories

```
$ ls -1d /etc/cron.*
/etc/cron.d
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.monthly
/etc/cron.weekly
```

for examples --- other packages put their jobs there (and this mechanism is more general, and newer, than direct editing of `/etc/crontab`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do to reindex and then restart the search daemon once a day.

```
* *     /1 * *  root    cd /home/sphinx && bin/indexer --all --rotate && bin/searchd --stop && bin/searchd
```